# How do I use require.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, requirejs

I have a folder that contains another folder and a file "server.js", the file is the node file and the folder contains HTML and client.js. server.js has a variable that holds the port for the website, and I want to access that variable to use it in the client.js, but it keeps erroring, I tried using import statement in the client.js but it gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". I tried using require("server.js") but learned that client-side js doesn't support require() function. I searched and found that there's a library called RequireJS, while there are some tutorials to use it, they all use the same example and it always gives the same error no matter how much I changed the code, so please help me with a detailed tutorial on how to use RequireJS.

Comment: You need to back up several steps and describe what you're trying to accomplish.  Is this server-side code or client-side code?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Then, please show the actual code you're trying to use.  As to your last sentence, we don't do detailed tutorials here.  We answer specific programming questions.  You need to ask a specific programming question.  If server.js is designed for server-side code, you will not be able to use it on the client.  Instead, you should probably dynamically insert to port into a client-side HTML file using a template.